# Saving eclipse .metadata not at workspace

Tags: eclipse

is there a opportunity to save the .metadata folder of eclipse (at workspace/.metadata) at another location on my disk without changing the workspace(for example: workspace is `/home/test/workspace` while the metadata folder is at `/home/test/anothersubfolder/.metadata`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The .metadata data is always in the root folder of the workspace.